# One-line short-circuit evaluation with && || in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, short-circuiting

```
var prefix = options && options.prefix || '';
```

In JavaScipt in my case. Can someone explain what kind of statement or condition is this? Or at the end what's the value of **prefix** variable?

I know about (ternary operator):

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

but this was different.

Comment: What about it don't you understand? `&&` is `AND`, and `||` is `OR`. What is `options`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one-liner is the equivalent of saying:

```
var prefix;
if(options && options.prefix){
  prefix = options.prefix;
} else{
  prefix = '';
}
```

Comment: What do they call this technique? I knew one-line conditions like: a==b?'1':'2';  but first time to see it short like this.

Comment: @PooyaSanooei - The example in your comment is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: @PooyaSanooei they are **different**, when `options.prefix` is `null` or `undefined`, these two statement return different value.

Comment: ternary operators are kinda different compared to this. here || works like :

Comment: It's called [Short-circuit Evaluation](https://echo.co/blog/short-circuit-evaluation-javascript-or-ternary-operator-binary). JavaScript's || operator will return the first non-falsy value, not a normalized boolean. It's a [shorten technique used in javascript](http://www.sitepoint.com/shorthand-javascript-techniques/).

Comment: I think it's bear mentioning that it's actually more equivalent to `if (options) { prefix = options.prefix; } else { prefix = ' '; }`, because if `options.prefix` was replaced with a function call, your answer would call it twice, which is not equivalent

Answer (score 3):

The statement is setting the variable "prefix" to either the value of "options.prefix", or an empty string, in such a way that if "options" does not exist, it does not throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this works is in Javascript logical operators evaluate to the value of the last operand.

So is options object exist, the && part of the expression will be evaulated to options.prefix.

If that is not set, the left part of the || expression will be false and the right part = the '' string - will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Its similar to following:

```
var prefix;
if(options){     // or for better understanding, its if(options != undefined)
    prefix = options.prefix;
}
else
    prefix = '';
```

Try the following fiddle for better understanding: 
`http://jsfiddle.net/n41tfnh4/1/`

Comment: this is actually more correct than the accepted answer because if `options.prefix` was replaced with a function call, the accepted answer would call it twice, which is incorrect. This version would only call it once, which is the correct behavior

Answer (score 1):

**Translated into human language**

If variable `options`is defined with some non-falsey value

and it also has a property `options.prefix` whose value is also non-falsey

then set the variable `prefix` with this `options.prefix` value.

*Otherwise*, our `prefix` is set to empty string by default.

---

**PS.** Quickly check the complete list of *falsey values* in JavaScript by google "*javascript falsy values*"

---

**Quicker explanation**

This is a quick value check (and get) of `options.prefix` which is empty string by default.

(without throwing an exception when `options` is undefined)

Comment: This technique is different from [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)? Looks like we use || instead of :

Comment: To make an equivalent result, you can use *ternary operators* also : `var prefix = options ? (options.prefix || '') : ''`

Answer (score 0):

It means, it `options` is an object, use `options.prefix`. If `options.prefix` is `undefined` or `null` or other falsy value, return empty string.

**Nearly** same meaning of `options ? options.prefix : ''`.

Answer (score 0):

If `prefix` is available on `options`, set it to `var prefix`. Otherwise, set it to an empty string.